# On Mouseover make text arc

Tags: mouseover, dhtml

I never have much luck trying to put code into this text area. 
My question is how to modify the on mouseover (jsfiddle) so that I start with (DHTML) text and when you mouseover it arcs the text, then mouse out it returns to the original position. Even a link to a site with help.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following methods to generate the arc and the text:

- [SVG](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Text#Text_on_a_Path)
- [CSS3](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/)
- [Raphael.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612764/attach-text-on-path-in-raphael)
- [CSSWarp generator](http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/)

Then bind a mouseover event to the container of the text content to produce the desired effect.