# Raphael JS Text Along path

Tags: javascript, raphael, webfonts

I am looking for an example or some confirmation on a concept. Looking to use Raphael JS on an app and want to be able to warp text similar to how graphic design applications such as Illustrator do.

[image: example of warped Text following a path]

Comment: This was from 2010:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612764/attach-text-on-path-in-raphael

Comment: Thanks CM Kanode. I found this earlier in my hunt. It does not show the concept of orienting the text to the path. I am being extremely lazy here, would you think orienting to the path would just be a simple bit of math or does your linked example kind of prove that orientation would be a problem in Raphael?

Comment: Check out this [fork](https://github.com/petecocoon/raphael) - author claims that he added textPath support. Only to SVG though.

Comment: I didn't look at it in depth.  Just a quick look at the concept which seemed sound.  Offhand, I'd lean towards thinking that it'd need a lot of tweaking by hand.  Hopefully, the fork mentioned by Andrei above provides the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: I've done something much like this using Raphael only, using `print` and `path.getPointAtLength`.  I seem to remember there was a bug in the `alpha` attribute that had to be corrected for when the path passes through PI/2, but it was quite functional.  Just to clarify: individual characters are not skewed; the skew is accomplished simply by translation and rotation of complete characters.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an adaptation of Chris Wilson's code, refactored as a drop-in function, with added features:

- **IE8 / VML mode support** and **Gecko/Firefox support** (by defining the rotation origin - without this, IE8 and Firefox go nuts throwing the text all around the page)
- A small adjustment to make text less ugly in Gecko browsers (e.g. **Firefox**) - without this, these increase the letter spacing arbitrarily
- Support for **manually defined font sizes and letter spacing**, as well as dynamic 'fill the path' sizes and spacing
- Support for manual **kerning** (fine-tuning letter spacing character by character). Text on a path often creates really ugly letter spaces; this allows you to define manual tweaks to fix these, by:

  - Numeric position in the string, or,
  - Character, or,
  - Character pairs (applying to instances of a character based on the preceding character, e.g. the below example tightens 'ae' pairs and widens 'rn' pairs)

### [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UJIYAco/1/)

```
function textOnPath( message, path, fontSize, letterSpacing, kerning, geckoKerning) {
    // only message and path are required, other args are optional
    // if fontSize or letterSpacing are undefined, they are calculated to fill the path
    // 10% of fontSize is usually good for manual letterspacing

    // Gecko, i.e. Firefox etc, inflates and alters the letter spacing
    var gecko = /rv:([^\)]+)\) Gecko\/\d{8}/.test(navigator.userAgent||'') ? true : false;

    var letters = [], places = [], messageLength = 0;
    for (var c=0; c < message.length; c++) {
        var letter = paper.text(0, 0, message[c]).attr({"text-anchor" : "middle"});
        letters.push(letter);

        if (kerning) {
            if(gecko && geckoKerning) {
                kerning = geckoKerning;
            }
            var character = letter.attr('text'), kern = 0;
            var predecessor = letters[c-1] ? letters[c-1].attr('text') : '';

            if (kerning[c]) {
                kern = kerning[c];
            } else if (kerning[character]) {
                if( typeof kerning[character] === 'object' ) {
                    kern = kerning[character][predecessor] || kerning[character]['default'] || 0;
                } else {
                    kern = kerning[character];
                }
            }
            if(kerning['default'] ) {
                kern = kern + (kerning['default'][predecessor] || 0);
            }            
            messageLength += kern;
        }

        places.push(messageLength);
        //spaces get a width of 0, so set min at 4px
        messageLength += Math.max(4.5, letter.getBBox().width);
    }

    if( letterSpacing ){
        if (gecko) {
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing * 0.83;
        }
    } else {
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing || path.getTotalLength() / messageLength;
    }
    fontSize = fontSize || 10 * letterSpacing;

    for (c = 0; c < letters.length; c++) {
        letters[c].attr("font-size", fontSize + "px");
        p = path.getPointAtLength(places[c] * letterSpacing);
        var rotate = 'R' + (p.alpha < 180 ? p.alpha + 180 : p.alpha > 360 ? p.alpha - 360 : p.alpha )+','+p.x+','+p.y;
    letters[c].attr({ x: p.x, y: p.y, transform: rotate });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Thank you for that! But I have a problem with adjusting the text to appear exactly in the center of the path. I asked for help here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047029/raphael-js-centered-text-on-path). Maybe you could have a look?

Comment: Text alignment for text on paths would be a useful feature. I had a quick look at it, and got this far - http://jsbin.com/UJIYAco/18/edit - it's a starting point, works on GC/FF/IE8+, but as you'll see the characters are always skewed a little too far to the right, sometimes bunching up at the end. The approach seems sound, but it needs something to counteract the rightward shift - for some reason it's either underestimating the length of the text or overestimating the length of the path.

Comment: Thank you for that! It seems to be working good enough for me! 

But now I have a different problem. I need the text printed on path to change it's attibutes (color in particular) on hover. Is it at all possible with your function given it's not the Raphael Paper element?

Comment: @zorza if you've got it working can you share what you did e.g. as an answer to your question?

Comment: This function has one bug and one place for improvement. 1) It does not center the text on path. Sometimes it might be intended, but not having an option to makes aligning texts a pain. 2) Letter rotation is broken, because a) it relies on Raphael's broken angle calculation (it is not consistent) b) it does not take path direction into account.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/friendzis/9362577
Here is my modified version to take my comments into account

Answer (score 6):

This isn't too difficult using path.getPointAtLength, as Kevin Nielsen suggests:

```
path = paper.path("M50,100c40,-50 270,50 300,0").attr("stroke", "#CCC");
message = "I want to do this in RaphaelJS";

//since not every letter is the same width, get the placement for each letter 
//along the length of the string
//however, Raphael appears to group the width of letters into intervals of 4px,
//so this won't be perfect        
for (; c < message.length; c += 1) {
        letter = paper.text(0, 0, message[c]).attr({"text-anchor" : "start"});
    letters.push(letter);
    places.push(message_length);
    //spaces get a width of 0, so set min at 4px
    message_length += Math.max(4, letter.getBBox().width);
}

ratio = path.getTotalLength() / message_length;
fontsize = 10 * ratio;

for (c = 0; c < letters.length; c += 1) {
    letters[c].attr("font-size", fontsize + "px"); 
    p = path.getPointAtLength(places[c] * ratio);
    //there does appear to be a bug in p.alpha around 180. Here's the fix
    letters[c].attr({ x: p.x, y: p.y, transform: 'r' + (p.alpha < 180 ? p.alpha + 180 : p.alpha)});
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/4UykA/)

Comment: Nice approach, +1, but in my testing this only worked in Webkit (Chrome, Safari etc) and IE9+. In **Firefox** and **IE8**, the text is thrown around and doesn't follow the path. I've posted an adapted version below (with rotation origin) that works in IE8+, Firefox and Webkit and has a few extra tweaks and features.