# How to use textPath for text in snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, text, svg, path, snap.svg

Is there a way to use textpath using SnapSVG? I tried using textPath as an attribute but it does not seem to add a textpath element in the text node.

```
var txtpth = s.path("M70 70 Q 80 90 200 150 L 200 400").attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "black"
 });
var crooked = s.text(0,0,"lorempsum ipsum lorempsum ipsum lorempsum ipsum lorempsum   ipsum").attr({
     textPath: txtpth,
     stroke:"black"
 });
```

I do not see a direct API to manipulate text paths in SVG using snap.svg.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach text on path in Raphaël?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612764/attach-text-on-path-in-raphael)

Comment: I am aware of the Raphael library and the API provided by these two frameworks are different. Its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a complete SVG xml with defs,path and textpath created a duplicate DEFS tag in an existing Snap document. I did something like below to evade that issue. Overall, the your solution seems to work.

```
var txt = s.text(50,50,"").attr({
    stroke: "black",
    fill:"none",
    fontFamily: "Helvetica Nueue, Helvetica, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: "bold"
});
var myFrag = Snap.parse('<path id="MyPath" d="M 50 200 C 200 100 300 0 400 100 C 500 200 600 300 700 200 C 800 100 900 100 900 100"/>');
var txtpath = Snap.parse('<textPath id="myTextPath" xlink:href="#MyPath">We go up, then we go down, then up again</textPath>');
var defns = s.select('defs');
defns.append(myFrag);
txt.append(txtpath);
console.log("Definitions: -->" + defns.toString());

console.log("Text Element: -->" + txt.toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Definitions: --><defs><radialGradient cx="145" cy="331" r="38"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffffff"/><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#4b4b7b"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#444444"/></radialGradient><rect width="10" height="10" class="svg---mgr"/><path id="MyPath" d="M 50 200 C 200 100 300 0 400 100 C 500 200 600 300 700 200 C 800 100 900 100 900 100"/></defs>

Text Element: --><text x="50" y="50" stroke="#000000" fill="none" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Nueue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;"><textPath id="myTextPath" xlink:href="#MyPath">We go up, then we go down, then up again</textPath></text>
```

However, I am not sure if this is a very elegant way to do it. I think there should be an API provided to achieve this. Preferably like taking in a textPath string, that internally does the same thing we did above.

Answer (score 2):

This option is now working in the latest dev version (0.2 onwards). So you can now do this type of thing....(this won't work on 0.1)

```
var s = Snap("#svgout"); 

var path = "M 100 200 C 200 100 300   0 400 100 C 500 200 600 300 700 200 C 800 100 900 100 900 100";

var text = s.text(50,50,'Hi there')
              .attr({ 'textpath': path })
              .textPath.animate({ 'startOffset': 2000 }, 5000 );
```

http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-textpath.html

Comment: In the dabbles example you can see that this produces a new path each time you click on the Run button. But you can do this: var path = s.path("M 100 200 C 200......"); and set this as object for the textpath attribute. Then you can reuse the path for further text operations. It seems that the path attribute does not have to be a string when using the attr function.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that looks like it may be a problem with my testing environment, where Snap isn't clearing that when I do a clear(). I'll see if I can fix that. I'm guessing that shouldn't happen on a normal page that someone will use live. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a bad way or not, but a workaround (as I couldn't figure it within Snap itself only), could be to parse in the SVG and use it..so something like this...

```
s = Snap(800, 800);

var myPath = "M70 70 Q 80 90 200 150 L 200 400";
var myText = "lorempsum ipsum lorempsum ipsum lorempsum ipsum lorempsum   ipsum";

var myFrag = Snap.parse('<defs><path id="MyPath" d="' + myPath + '" /> </defs> \
   <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="42.5"> \
     <textPath id="myTextPath" xlink:href="#MyPath">' + myText + '</textPath> \
   </text>\
 ');

s.append( myFrag );
var tp = s.select("#myTextPath");
tp.animate({ 'startOffset': 2000 }, 5000 );
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Wetw4/5/ Its not ideal, but may give some ideas.