# Raphaeljs - Warp printed-text effects like arch, curve and pinch

Tags: svg, raphael

I was wondering if there is any starting point to understand how to Warp Printed Texts created with RaphaelJS Print method. By "Warp Shape Effects" I mean:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0053gix947

- Arch
- Curve
- ...

by Printed-Text I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/jorozco/ub50nbbj/3/

```
window.onload = function () {

    var r = Raphael( "paper", 300, 300 );

    var x = 40;
    var y = 140;
    var str = "Warping Printed Text";
    var font = r.getFont("ChunkFive");
    var fontSize = 20;

    p = r.print( x, y, str, font, fontSize ).attr({
        fill: "#0073be"
    });

};
```

The text is an SVG Path (not a set of paths for each characater). The only site I found doing it right is: Inksoft, and seems that they are using transform to alter the warp effect of the whole text path.

There is a lot of info about how to apply effects to plain texts using CSS or paths to follow. But for printed paths the mechanic is different. I am a little bit lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stack OVerflow

Comment: if there is any method available to extend our knowledge on "warp shape effects" is welcome.

Comment: Do you have any examples on another site to highlight what you mean ?

Comment: the links show a forbidden error :)

Comment: Hi @Ian! looks like the links are working fine.

Comment: Wondering if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612764/attach-text-on-path-in-rapha%C3%ABl would help.

Comment: Seems very different to the transformations applied by Inksoft. Thanks @Ian! I am going to try it.